# Youtube api not loading YouTubePlayerView on newer android device

Tags: youtube-api

You tube api is working fine when I test it on an older android device but on a newer device it won't load.

Yes the device does have the youtube app updated.

#### I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The concrete class implementing IObjectWrapper must have exactly *one* declared private field for the wrapped object.  Preferably, this is an instance of the ObjectWrapper<T> class.
        at aolk.a(SourceFile:13)
        at com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.<init>(SourceFile:42)
```

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://github.com/viromedia/virocore/issues/96). Try to deactivate `Instant Run` and check if it's working. It was already reported that there might be [issues](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/130) with Android Studio and Google's latest version of ARCore that causes the crashes above.